# Can we execute Progress Query Online

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am new to the Progress and OpenEdge environment.

Where can I get access to development tools so that I can get started learning more about OpenEdge?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What does online mean? What version of Progress are you using? What is the OS?

Comment: Hi Austin,
           Thanks for reply.
I am not using any version of progress. i just want to execute progress query online for practice purpose .if it's possible please send me link. If u have any doc for progress 4gl please provide me .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No.  You cannot execute Progress 4GL "online".

You must obtain a license and install it.  For evaluation and learning purposes there is a free "classroom edition" available at:

https://www.progress.com/openedge/pricing

All OpenEdge documentation is also online:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/1329.openedge-product-documentation-overview

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Tom,
Thanks for your reply.
Can u please send me Beginner Level Progress doc  or any link . 


Thanks

Comment: I've added a documentation link to the answer

Comment: How to install openedge 11.6 in windows operating system.

Comment: Hi Tom,
I have installed this zip 
https://progress-eval.subscribenet.com/control/prge/download?agree=Accept&element=6778127

can you guide me how to install this s/w.

Thanks,
Purushottam

Comment: I don't know how to help you install something that you say you have already installed.  You might try contacting tech support.